# Value of onedrive URI respose

Tags: 20.04

I run 'onedrive' from the terminal and am asked to visit a URL like:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=22c49a0d-d21c-4792-aed1-8f163c982546&scope=Files.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite.all%20Sites.ReadWrite.All%20offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

When I do I see a blank page with the URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?code=M.R3_BL2.170155b3-56c0-8a7c-a113-3aa39e8471bc

Then I'm asked for the URI...what is it?

Thanks
-bill

Answer (score 0):

> Then I'm asked for the URI...what is it?

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

It (the URI being asked for) is the URL in the browser that you have posted - which by the way, is now a security risk to your OneDrive account as you have posted your response code token (not good) - please change your OneDrive account password urgently.

Additionally, your question + answer is detailed here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#authorize-the-application-with-your-onedrive-account

Also - make sure you install the onedrive client the correct way - ie: do ***not*** install via `sudo apt install onedrive` without using the Ubuntu PPA. If you do not use the PPA you will install an out-of-date version with known issues. Refer to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md for the correct details to install the client on Ubuntu

Additionally, as a side note, the client identifier you are currently using indicates you are using the 'skilion' codebase and that client contains major defects that put you at risk of data loss. The ;skilion' client was abandoned by the developer in 2018 and despite a new version release in Oct 2020, these defects remain.